# R language sqldf package update table not working

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

i exported some data from a csv file into R. i am using sqldf package to udpate data. My below query runs. i can provide my csv file but i dont know how to attach files here :(

```
> sqldf("select * from
+ (
+  
+ select Disposition as dummy_disposition, case Disposition
+ when 'Disposition' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ when 'Donate' then  'EOL'
+ when 'Resale' then  'EOL'
+ when 'Harvest' then  'EOL'
+ when 'IntelSpinOff' then  'EOL'
+ when 'Scrap' then  'EOL'
+ when 'BufferFeedForward' then   'ACTIVE'
+ when 'FB' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ when 'Unknown' then  'UNKOWN'
+ when 'HarvestResale' then  'EOL'
+ when 'ReturnToSupplier' then  'EOL'
+ when 'IcapResale' then  'EOL'
+ when 'NonEmsManaged' then  'EOL'
+ when 'BufferEOL' then  'EOL'
+ when 'ResaleScrap' then  'EOL'
+ when 'ST' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ when 'AS' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ else null end as new_status,
+  
+ *  from a where FloorStatus is null and  disposition is not null
+  
+  
+ )  as table1
+   where new_status is null")
 [1] dummy_disposition new_status        Ueid              Date              EndDate          
 [6] Site              CFD               Type              ScheduleId        EventType        
[11] FloorStatus       EntityCode        Ceid              Process           Supplier         
[16] FA                MfgType           Disposition       Comments          extra1           
[21] extra2            extra3           
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

but when i run below query it doesnt run :( It is interesting because except update table part rest of the query is part of the above query.

```
> sqldf("update a set FloorStatus = case Disposition
+ when 'Disposition' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ when 'Donate' then  'EOL'
+ when 'Resale' then  'EOL'
+ when 'Harvest' then  'EOL'
+ when 'IntelSpinOff' then  'EOL'
+ when 'Scrap' then  'EOL'
+ when 'BufferFeedForward' then   'ACTIVE'
+ when 'FB' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ when 'Unknown' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ when 'HarvestResale' then  'EOL'
+ when 'ReturnToSupplier' then  'EOL'
+ when 'IcapResale' then  'EOL'
+ when 'NonEmsManaged' then  'EOL'
+ when 'BufferEOL' then  'EOL'
+ when 'ResaleScrap' then  'EOL'
+ when 'ST' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ when 'AS' then  'UNKNOWN'
+ else null end
+    from a where FloorStatus is null and  disposition is not null")
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: near "from": syntax error)
```

what is wrong with my update table command? when i run my code in sql development studio it runs fine...but  i would prefer if code runs in R

UPDATE:

what changes do i need to make to the below code????

```
declare @outputs table 
([day] datetime,
floorstatus varchar,  
 quantity int)

declare @Date datetime;


DECLARE dates_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT clndr_dt from epsd.dbo.t_calendar
              where clndr_dt between '2008-01-01' and '2013-08-13'
              order by clndr_dt
OPEN dates_cursor
FETCH NEXT from dates_cursor INTO @Date

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

insert @outputs
       select @Date as [Day], floorstatus, count(floorstatus) as quantity from Graph_data
       where @Date between [Date] and EndDate
       group by floorstatus

FETCH NEXT from dates_cursor INTO @Date
END
CLOSE dates_cursor
DEALLOCATE dates_cursor

select * from @outputs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update does not have a `from` clause (see [update syntax on SQLite site](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)) and also see [sqldf FAQ #8](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#8._Why_am_I_having_problems_with_update?) for the commonly made error of updating the table in SQLite but then not returning the table to R.

Comment: your suggestion helped...any idea about my update/new question?

Comment: In sqldf you do it all at once rather than row by row.  If the question is basically how to insert variables see Example 5 on the sqldf home page.  https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_5._Insert_Variables

Comment: my question is a bit different...i am writing a cursor as i want to iterate through my data. Each row of my data has 2 columns - start and end date. i will be starting with 1-1-2008 and will be counting entries in some other column if my date is withing start and end date column. I am writing a cursor as writing a cursor is quite easy and it provides fast output. My cursor code didnt run in R. is there a better way to achieve the same in R and sqldf? thanks

Comment: You can use a `where` or `limit` clause to grab a part of the output or if size is not a problem just get it all at once.  Alternately use the RSQLite package which does support cursors.